# Golang - Slice Performance append has better performance than assign

Tags: go

I am trying to understand performance of slice appends vs assigns in Golang, and I would have thought generally an assign would be better, but in this bit of code, it looks like append is better.  I am trying to figure out why - but am struggling with it.

This is a Merge Sorted Array in Leetcode and version 1 below gives me Runtime of 3 ms

```
func merge(nums1 []int, m int, nums2 []int, n int)  {
    
    tmpSlice := make([]int, m+n)
    tmpIndex := 0
    index1 := 0
    index2 := 0
    
    for index1 < m {
        value1 := nums1[index1]
        for index2 < n {
            value2 := nums2[index2]
            if value1 <= value2 {
                break
            } else {
                tmpSlice[tmpIndex] = value2    \\ <-- Assign
                index2++
                tmpIndex++          
            }
        }
        tmpSlice[tmpIndex] = value1    \\ <-- Assign
        index1++
        tmpIndex++ 
    }
    

    copy(nums1, tmpSlice[:tmpIndex])
    copy(nums1[tmpIndex:], nums2[index2:])

}
```

Version 2 below gives me a Runtime of 0 ms

```
func merge(nums1 []int, m int, nums2 []int, n int)  {
   
    tmpSlice := make([]int, 0, m+n)
    tmpIndex := 0
    index1 := 0
    index2 := 0
    
    for index1 < m {
        value1 := nums1[index1]
        for index2 < n {
            value2 := nums2[index2]
            if value1 <= value2 {
                break
            } else {
                tmpSlice = append(tmpSlice, value2)    \\ <-- Append
                index2++
                tmpIndex++          
            }
        }
        tmpSlice = append (tmpSlice, value1)    \\ <-- Append
        index1++
        tmpIndex++ 
    }
    

    copy(nums1, tmpSlice[:tmpIndex])
    copy(nums1[tmpIndex:], nums2[index2:])

}
```

The only difference in the two versions is the append vs assign, and the append is faster.  Append is checking for memory allocation and then doing an assign, right?  Shouldn't Append be slower?

Comment: How did you benchmark and why do you think one should be faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put both in a benchmarks, performance between the two is almost equal, `append` is slower, but by an almost negligible amount.

```golang
package main_test

import "testing"

func BenchmarkMerge1(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        num1 := []int{1, 2, 3}
        num2 := []int{4, 5, 6}
        merge1(num1, len(num1), num2, len(num2))
    }
}

func merge1(nums1 []int, m int, nums2 []int, n int) {

    tmpSlice := make([]int, m+n)
    tmpIndex := 0
    index1 := 0
    index2 := 0

    for index1 < m {
        value1 := nums1[index1]
        for index2 < n {
            value2 := nums2[index2]
            if value1 <= value2 {
                break
            } else {
                tmpSlice[tmpIndex] = value2 // <-- Assign
                index2++
                tmpIndex++
            }
        }
        tmpSlice[tmpIndex] = value1 // <-- Assign
        index1++
        tmpIndex++
    }

    copy(nums1, tmpSlice[:tmpIndex])
    copy(nums1[tmpIndex:], nums2[index2:])
}

func BenchmarkMerge2(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        num1 := []int{1, 2, 3}
        num2 := []int{4, 5, 6}
        merge2(num1, len(num1), num2, len(num2))
    }
}

func merge2(nums1 []int, m int, nums2 []int, n int) {
    tmpSlice := make([]int, 0, m+n)
    tmpIndex := 0
    index1 := 0
    index2 := 0

    for index1 < m {
        value1 := nums1[index1]
        for index2 < n {
            value2 := nums2[index2]
            if value1 <= value2 {
                break
            } else {
                tmpSlice = append(tmpSlice, value2) // <-- Append
                index2++
                tmpIndex++
            }
        }
        tmpSlice = append(tmpSlice, value1) // <-- Append
        index1++
        tmpIndex++
    }

    copy(nums1, tmpSlice[:tmpIndex])
    copy(nums1[tmpIndex:], nums2[index2:])
}
```

```
Running tool: /usr/local/go/bin/go test -benchmem -run=^$ -bench ^(BenchmarkMerge1|BenchmarkMerge2)$ example.com/m

goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: example.com/m
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10870H CPU @ 2.20GHz
BenchmarkMerge1-16      34586568            36.40 ns/op       48 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkMerge2-16      32561293            36.77 ns/op       48 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
ok      example.com/m   2.533s
```

This is to be expected since append basically does an assignment as long as the slice has capacity. `append` also increment the `len` field in the slice header(thx @rustyx for that hint), which explains the difference.

You will see a larger difference when not setting an initial capacity on the slice and using append since it will "grow" the underlying array which takes time.

If we change `tmpSlice := make([]int, 0, m+n)` to `tmpSlice := make([]int, 0)` in `merge2` we get this result:

```golang
Running tool: /usr/local/go/bin/go test -benchmem -run=^$ -bench ^(BenchmarkMerge1|BenchmarkMerge2)$ example.com/m

goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: example.com/m
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10870H CPU @ 2.20GHz
BenchmarkMerge1-16      37319397            32.34 ns/op       48 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkMerge2-16      14543529            87.75 ns/op       56 B/op          3 allocs/op
PASS
ok      example.com/m   2.604s
```

TL;DR, `append` is slower than assigning(since the `len` field in the slice is incremented), by an almost negligible amount, as long as the slice has capacity

Comment: Makes sense.  I didn't benchmark it myself, I was using LeetCode's numbers for performance, but there's probably other variables in it.  Thanks all.